# Multiple queries to Postgres within the same function

Tags: go, go-gin, go-pg

I'm new to Go, so sorry for the silly question in advance!

I'm using Gin framework and want to make multiple queries to the database within the same handler (`database/sql` + `lib/pq`)

```
userIds := []int{}
bookIds := []int{}
var id int

/* Handling first query here */
rows, err := pgClient.Query(getUserIdsQuery)
defer rows.Close()
if err != nil {
    return
}
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    userIds = append(userIds, id)
}

/* Handling second query here */
rows, err = pgClient.Query(getBookIdsQuery)
defer rows.Close()
if err != nil {
    return
}
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    bookIds = append(bookIds, id)
}
```

I have a couple of questions regarding this code (any improvements and best practices would be appreciated)

1. Does Go properly handle `defer rows.Close()` in such a case? I mean I have reassignment of `rows` variable later down the code, so will compiler track both and properly close at the end of a function?
2. Is it ok to reuse `id` shared var or should I redeclare it while iterating within `rows.Next()` loop?
3. What's the better approach of having even more queries within one handler? Should I have some kind of `Writer` that accepts query and slice and populate it with ids retrieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never worked with `go-pg` library, and my answer is mostly focused on the other stuff, which are generic, and are not specific to golang or go-pg.

- 1. Regardless of the fact that the `rows` here has the same reference while being shared between 2 queries (so one `rows.Close()` call would suffice, unless the library has some special implementation), defining two variables is cleaner, like `userRows` and `bookRows`.
- 2. Although I already said that I have not worked with `go-pg`, I believe that you wont need to iterate through rows and scan the id for all the rows manually, I believe that the lib has provided some API like this (based on the quick look on the documentations):

  ```
  userIds := []int{}
  err := pgClient.Query(&userIds, "select id from users where ...", args...)
  ```
- 3. Regarding your second question, it depends on what you mean by "ok". Since your doing some synchronous iteration, I don't think it would result into bugs, but when it comes to coding style, personally, I wouldn't do this.
- 4. I think that the best thing to do in your case is this:

  ```
  // repo layer
  func getUserIds(args whatever) ([]int, err) {...}
  // these can be exposed, based on your packaging logic
  func getBookIds(args whatever) ([]int, err) {...}

  // service layer, or wherever you want to aggregate both queries
  func getUserAndBookIds() ([]int, []int, err) {
      userIds, err := getUserIds(...)
      // potential error handling
      bookIds, err := getBookIds(...)
      // potential error handling
      return userIds, bookIds, nil // you have done err handling earlier
  }
  ```

  I think this code is easier to read/maintain. You won't face the variable reassignment and other issues.

You can take a look at the [go-pg documentations](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v10#section-readme) for more details on how to improve your query.